# Php form validation not working for me

Tags: php, validation

I have tried with below code. the code only validating "yourname". 
yourlname and umobile not validating. Please let me know the mistake which I have done in the code.

```
if(strlen($yourname)<4) 
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short!'));
    die($output);
}
if(strlen($yourlname)) 
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter Last Name'));
    die($output);
}

if(strlen($umobile)) 
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter Mobile Number'));
    die($output);
}
```

Comment: `strlen` Returns the length of a string on success, and 0 if the string is empty and you always enter in if condition. Instead use `!empty($yourlname){}`

Comment: Because the condition its validating fine is the only correct one you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
  if(!strlen(trim($yourlname)))
```

And

```
 if(!strlen(trim($umobile)))
```

Comment: I can't able to click on that,